# How to convert several duplicate rows into an array in SQL (Postgres)?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have the following table `One`:

```
 id │ value 
────┼───────
  1 │ a
  2 │ b
```

And `Two`:

```
  id │ value 
─────┼───────
  10 │ a
  20 │ a
  30 │ b
  40 │ a
  50 │ b
```

`One.value` has a unique constraint but not `Two.value` (one-to-many relationship).

Which SQL (Postgres) query will retrieve **as array** the `id`s of `Two` whose value match `One.value`? The result I am looking for is:

```
          id │ value 
─────────────┼───────
  {10,20,40} │ a
     {30,50} │ b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check on <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08396/2)</kbd>

```
SELECT array_agg(id) AS id, "value"
  FROM Two
 GROUP BY "value";
```

Using `value` as identifier (column name here) is a bad practice, as it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Thank you for the extra tip about "value"